# csv.writer writing each character of word in separate column/cell

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

Objective: To extract the text from the anchor tag inside all lines in `models` and put it in a csv.

I'm trying this code:

```
with open('Sprint_data.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
  spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
  models = soup.find_all('li' , {"class" : "phoneListing"})

  for model in models:

      model_name = unicode(u' '.join(model.a.stripped_strings)).encode('utf8').strip()
      spamwriter.writerow(unicode(u' '.join(model.a.stripped_strings)).encode('utf8').strip())
```

It's working fine except each cell in the csv contains only one character.

Like this:

```
|  S  |  A  |   M  |   S  |   U   |  N  |   G   |
```

Instead of:

```
|SAMSUNG|
```

Of course I'm missing something. But what?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`writerow` accepts a sequence.  You're giving it a single string, so it's treating that as a sequence, and strings act like sequences of characters.

What else do you want in this row?  Nothing?  If so, make it a list of one item:

```
spamwriter.writerow([u' '.join(model.a.stripped_strings).encode('utf8').strip()])
```

(By the way, the `unicode()` call is completely unnecessary since you're already joining with a unicode delimiter.)

Answer (score 113):

`.writerow()` requires a sequence (`''`, `()`, `[]`) and places each index in it's own column of the row, sequentially.  If your desired string is not an item in a sequence, `writerow()` will iterate over each letter in your string and each will be written to your CSV in a separate cell.

after you `import csv`

If this is your list:

```
myList = ['Diamond', 'Sierra', 'Crystal', 'Bridget', 'Chastity', 'Jasmyn', 'Misty', 'Angel', 'Dakota', 'Asia', 'Texxxas', 'Desiree', 'Monique', 'Tatiana']


listFile = open('Strippers.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(listFile)
for item in myList:
    writer.writerow(item)
```

The above script will produce the following CSV:
strippers.csv

```
D,i,a,m,o,n,d
S,i,e,r,r,a
C,r,y,s,t,a,l
B,r,i,d,g,e,t
C,h,a,s,t,i,t,y
J,a,s,m,y,n
M,i,s,t,y
A,n,g,e,l
D,a,k,o,t,a
A,s,i,a
T,e,x,x,x,a,s
D,e,s,i,r,e,e
M,o,n,i,q,u,e
T,a,t,i,a,n,a
```

If you want each name in it's own cell, the solution is to simply place your string (`item`) in a sequence.  Here I use square brackets `[]`.  :

```
listFile2 = open('Strippers2.csv', 'wb')
writer2 = csv.writer(listFile2)
for item in myList:
    writer2.writerow([item])
```

The script with `.writerow([item])` produces the desired results:
Strippers2.csv

```
Diamond
Sierra
Crystal
Bridget
Chastity
Jasmyn
Misty
Angel
Dakota
Asia
Texxxas
Desiree
Monique
Tatiana
```

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to write the whole list in the csv without using the `for` loop?

Answer (score 8):

This is usually the solution I use:

```
import csv
    with open("output.csv", 'w', newline= '') as output:
        wr = csv.writer(output, dialect='excel')
        for element in list_of_things:
            wr.writerow([element])
        output.close()
```

This should provide you with an output of all your list elements in a single column rather than a single row.

Key points here is to iterate over the list and use '[list]' to avoid the csvwriter sequencing issues.

Hope this is of use!

Comment: This is honestly amazing and should get more votes imo. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 6):

Just surround it with a list sign (i.e **[]**)

```
writer.writerow([str(one_column_value)])
```